# My functions and if statements don't seem to be working

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
 import time

def temp():
    print(script)
    print(a,sce1)
    print(b,sce2)
    print(c,sce3)
    print(d,sce4)
    choice = str(input())
    return choice
    if choice =="i":
        print(inventory)
    if choice =="p":
        print(storyline_varable)


script = ""
a = ""
b = ""
c = ""
d = ""
sce1 = ""
sce2 = ""
sce3 = ""
sce4 = ""
choice = ""
inventory = list((""))
storyline_variable = list((""))


print("Welcome to choice dungeon! Go through this dangerous place by typing the letter of the choice you'd like to make (also type 'i' to see your inventory and 'p' to see important choices made), good luck!")
time.sleep(4)


#start
script = "You lay shackled to a wall in a room with damp walls made of rough stone, you are cold and wet, what do you do?"
sce1 = "Pull the shackles"
sce2 = "Shout for help"
sce3 = "Sit in the cold dark room for a while"
sce4 = "Start nawing your hand off"
a = "a-"
b = "b-"
c = "c-"
d = "d-"

if temp() == "a" or temp() == "ba" or temp() == "ca":
    #a&ba&ca
    script = "Your shackles break free, there is a dimmly lit room with a skeleton, a torch and a closed door"
    sce1 = "Grab the torch"
    sce2 = "Search the skeleton"
    sce3 = "Go through the door"
    a = "aa-"
    b = "ab-"
    c = "ac-"
    d = "ad-"

if temp() == "b":
    #b&cb&db
    storyline_variable.append("Someone has been woken up")
    script = "You call for hours to no avail, until you hear a faint shout from a distance: 'Shut up'. Try another option"
    sce1 = "Pull the shackles"
    sce2 = "Shout for help...again"
    sce3 = "Sit in the cold dark room for a while"
    sce4 = "Start nawing your hand off"
    a = "ba-"
    b = "bb-"
    c = "bc-"
    d = "bd-"

if temp() == "c" or temp() == "bc" or temp() == "cc":
    #c&cc
    script = "You just sit there, it's a bit uncomfortable and a tad boring but it isn't that bad. Try another option"
    sce1 = "Pull the shackles"
    sce2 = "Shout for help"
    sce3 = "Sit there more"
    sce4 = "Start nawing your hand off"
    a = "ca-"
    b = "cb-"
    c = "cc-"
    d = "cd-"

if temp() == "d" or temp() == "bd" or temp() == "cd":
    print("Was it worth it? You bled out... ouch")

else:
    print("Pressing a random button doesn't help you know? You know what? You died for being stupid")
```

Here is the full code I can't seem to get working, can anyone help?
I am not 100% on how functions work and how to use them within an if statement, how would I fix it?
The only thing that displays the correct message is if I put 'a' then 'b' then 'c' then 'd', anything else repeats the #start line and I am unable to figure out why.
As you can probably see I am making a dungeons and dragons esque game and you may also be able to tell I am relatively new to using python, I am very sorry if I am unable to understand the answers you give. Also keep in mind this code is designed to carry on through the 'dungeon' so may have some elements showing this.

Comment: So, what exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No it just isn't doing the correct things, after entering "a" as the input 'choice' the programme just stops

Comment: Please describe first what you want to do, then show a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the expected output.

Comment: How is that not correct? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: What is `choice`?

Comment: Where do you enter `'a'`? All I see is a `NameError`, because nowhere is `choice` defined in your main code. Certainly, your problem must be that you are merely defining a local variable `choice` in your `temp` function, which gets discarded immediately after the function is done running.

Answer (score 0):

The logical problem in your script is a simple one: You set the variable `choice` inside the function `temp`. You should set the variable before testing it. You could do that by putting the first execution of `temp` before the `if...`

Furthermore, it would be a good idea, to pass parameters to the function, so that you stop using global variables to make your script simpler.

```
def temp():
    print(script)
    print(a,sce1)
    print(b,sce2)
    print(c,sce3)
    choice = str(input())
    return choice

#start
script = "You lay shackled to a wall in a room with damp walls made of rough stone, you are cold and wet, what do you do?"
sce1 = "Pull the shackles"
sce2 = "Shout for help"
sce3 = "Sit in the cold dark room for a while"
sce4 = "Start nawing your hand off"
a = "a-"
b = "b-"
c = "c-"
d = "d-"
choice = temp()
if choice == "a":
    #a
    script = "Your shackles break free, there is a dimmly lit room with a skeleton, a torch and a closed door"
    sce1 = "Grab the torch"
    sce2 = "Search the skeleton"
    sce3 = "Go through the door"
    a = "a-"
    b = "b-"
    c = "c-"
    choice = temp()
```

Comment: After editing my code using your tips, instead of the program closing, it repeats the #start line.

Comment: you mean the script line?

Answer (score 0):

```
def tmp(n):
    print(story[n]['script'])
    print('a- ' + story[n]['sce1'])
    print('b- ' + story[n]['sce2'])
    print('c- ' + story[n]['sce3'])
    print('d- ' + story[n]['sce4'])

story = [{
             'script': "You lay shackled to a wall in a room with damp walls made of rough stone, you are cold and wet, what do you do?",
             'sce1': "Pull the shackles",
             'sce2': "Shout for help",
             'sce3': "Sit in the cold dark room for a while",
             'sce4': "Start nawing your hand off"
},
{
             'script': "Your shackles break free, there is a dimmly lit room with a skeleton, a torch and a closed door",
             'sce1': "Grab the torch",
             'sce2': "Search the skeleton",
             'sce3': "Go through the door",
             'sce4': "Start nawing your hand off"
},
]
tmp(0)
inp = input()
if inp == 'a':
    tmp(1)
```

Comment: I initialized choice before the function. I tried to change the original code as little as possible. In my opinion there is no need for a choice variable at all.

Comment: ah i get what you are saying. I'll make the changes

Comment: This works well, I will carry on the code and report back if anything goes wrong, thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't understand why you print proceed?

Comment: That's just as an example of usage. Instead of printing proceed you would repeat the script = "", sce1 = "" etc steps. I put the proceed in as a filler. You are supposed to replace it with your code

Comment: I did minimal changes to your code. But I would suggest you use a list of dictionary to store your entire storyline and then run through it using loops and conditions. It will reduce code repetition and make your code simple.

Comment: Oh , just as I thought, sorry for the misunderstanding. How would I implement this into my code, as I said I'm not a very experienced coder so I'm afraid I don't understand.